# How to present apns token in view controller?

Tags: ios, swift, apple-push-notifications, viewcontroller

I don't understand how to present the apns token as a string in view-controller. tried a lot of things and nothings worked out. in swift 4.

Comment: can you elaborate your question

Comment: show what you tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.**

You can save it to UserDefaults as Halil suggested like so:

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(yourAPNSToken, forKey: "APNSToken")
```

And retrieve it inside your ViewController:

```
let token = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "APNSToken")
```

**2.**

Or you can create new variable inside AppDelegate and access it from your VC

In your AppDelegate:

```
public var token = String()

token = yourAPNSToken
```

And inside your VC

```
let newToken = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).token
```

Answer (score 1):

Save Device token in  UserDefaults from AppDelegate didregisterforremotenotificationswithdevicetoken then use in other viewController.

Answer (score 0):

Once your app register for APNS and you get DeviceToken as a Data in your didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken you can convert that data in to the string like this.

```
 var token: String = deviceToken.description.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet(charactersIn: "<>"))
 token = token.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "")
 print("device token ---\(token)")
```

And if you want to store it in User default then use this.

```
 UserDefaults.standard.set(token, forKey: "deviceToken")
```